# Azure PutBlock max blocks

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have some Javascript which uploads a file in slices to azure storage blob, using PutBlock then when all blocks uploaded a PutBlockList request is called to put it all together.  This works perfectly, till I have more than 22 slices.  Does anyone know the maximum amount of blocks allowed?  Seems to cap it at 22?

By the way I am using the Azure Storage Emulator.

Comment: Max number of blocks allowed are 50000.

Comment: Gaurav... Did you write an article on uploading in chunks?  If so I think I might have based my code on your article.

Comment: If you mean this: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/, then yes. Can you please share what error you're getting? That would certainly help in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179467.aspx) for the underlying Azure Storage REST API:

> The maximum number of blocks that may be committed is 50,000, and the
>   maximum size of a blob that may be committed via the Put Block List
>   operation is 200 GB. If you attempt to commit more than 50,000 blocks,
>   the service returns status code 413 (Request Entity Too Large). The
>   service also returns additional information about the error in the
>   response, including the maximum number of blocks permitted.

You need to be careful about obeying the rules, specifically the [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135726.aspx):

> For a given blob, all block IDs must be the same length. If a block is
>   uploaded with a block ID of a different length than the block IDs for
>   any existing uncommitted blocks, the service returns error response
>   code 400 (Bad Request).